# Azure VM blocks page requests from specific ip

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

We have a VM with the following DNS on Azure:

erpone-jsl.cloudapp.net

Frequently the Default Website on this VM becomes inaccessible with the error message 'this web page can not be displayed.' However this happens only for those users who are using a particular internet service provider in the Western part of India.
If this particular ISP resets its server, the site becomes accessible.

OR if we restart this particular VM, the site becomes accessible.

But the problem recurs after a few hours or few days.

We noticed that the issue recurs when Windows 2012 (Datacenter) updates itself on the VM - but we are not sure of this, yet.

The IP pool from where this problem occurs is 116.199.168.0 to 116.199.168.21

This ISP is telling us that their IP is being blocked by Azure VM Firewall but we have not blocked or restricted any IP from our VM or IIS.

Can some one throw light on this strange phenomenon-

Page requests coming from only this range of IP is unable to access the website
but it resolves temporarily when either the VM is restarted or the ISP's Server is restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's happening in this particular case, but... Windows Azure doesn't offer a per-cloud-service firewall that provides IP-blocking. This is done at the VM level (your VMs).

That said: Have you tried accessing any other Windows Azure cloud services from those IP addresses which are having trouble accessing [erpone-jsl.cloudapp.net](http://erpone-jsl.cloudapp.net)? This would be a good test to perform, with *test* web applications in the same data center as erpone-jsl as well as one in another data center. You can also try putting a test website up in Azure Web Sites, free tier, which will let you deploy something in just a few minutes, with no cost, for testing purposes. You can use ftp to download diagnostic logs from Web Sites.

One thing you can do is inspect the IIS logs (Virtual Machines, or web/worker roles of Cloud Services), to see if the offending IP addresses show up in the log (and I'd suggest checking the logs of the *test* web site cloudapp.net's as well).

If all else fails, you can then open a support ticket, to see if Azure support has any light to shed on this.

Comment: Thanks David!

Our VM's firewall has no such rule. We have a similar site on another Azure VM. Same problem occurs when users access it through the same ISP.

The ISP says because of static ip, Azure firewall assumes this is a worm/dos attack & blocks this ip. When they did a TraceIP, it stalls after it reaches MSN network.

When the website was on Win08 R2 SP1 there was  no such issue and this has surfaced only after we switched over to Win-12 Server Datacenter, since 1-Feb-13.

Also VM's Event Viewer reports Google Update Service has stopped - perhaps it is not relevant in this context.